# Record webcam automated with unknown duration

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, webcam, h.264, directshow

I need to record (not stream) from my webcam, convert it to H.264 and store it in a mp4-container. With VLC media player I can do this manually with the Open Capture Device menu where I just have to press "convert" and set destination file and video codec.

But I need to do this automated, e.g. with command line or as batch - so that I can start recording from another program - and I don't know how to do that. Second problem is that I don't know the duration beforehand so I need also a possibility to stop recording (maybe a start and stop command ?).

EDIT: I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on a UNIXy system,

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 out.mpeg
```

works for me. You can press <kbd>q</kbd> or send `SIGTERM` to the process to stop recording.

Comment: I'm using Win7. Sry, for not being specific enough.

Comment: @Chris Ah, ok. I don't have a Windows handy to test on, but [some clues](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.videolan.vlc.devel/72773) would indicate you can do something similar with `vlc.exe` from Windows' command line, though obviously with different flags. Worth investigating.